# How to pass pointer to string in a circular buffer of uint16_t in c?

Tags: c, string, buffer, circular-dependency

I have a fully functional circular buffer of `uint16_t` (for a 16bit machine). I want to stock string in it.
Functions used are :

```
void bufCirPut(buf_c_gest cbuf, uint16_t data); //put data, first argument is a pointer to circular buffer
int bufCirGet(buf_c_gest cbuf, uint16_t * data); //Retrieve data
```

For now I tried

```
char data1[10]="hello";
char *p_data1= &data1;
bufCirPut(buf_c_test, p_data1);
uint16_t donnee1;
bufCirGet(buf_c_test, &donnee1);
printf("%u\n ", donnee1);
```

I get memory adress (I guess, it's like 220, 230,216...) how to go to back to the string please?

EDIT : The aim for the buffer is that a sensor fills the buffer with a string and another devices read the buffer for information. Theses buffers will also be used to pass `uint16_t` between flash storage. So I try to have a unique solution for both usage.

Comment: You can't do what you want on anything but a 16-bit system where memory addresses (pointers) are 16 bits. On a 32-bit system where pointers are 32 bits, you simply can't fit those 32 bits into a 16-bit type, and it's even more impossible on a 64-bit system. Why do you want to store pointers (to strings or other data) in a queue that stores only 16-bit integers? What is the *real* and *actual* problem you need to solve?

Comment: I program on a 64 bit machine but the objectif is to run a 16bit microcontroler, so the 16bit machine should assign memory addresses of 16 bit no?

Comment: If the target system have a 16-bit address-space then it's possible. If your compiler and library support it I would then do the conversion using casting and with `uintptr_t` type as intermediate, such as `bufCirPut(buf_c_test, (uint16_t) (uintptr_t) data1)` But note that this will only work on the target system (or in a suitably setup emulator).

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, I will keep updated when I access the system in few days

Comment: Be aware that only the *pointer* is stored, the way you do it currently. You need to be sure that the string it points to will be still accessible (and unmodified) at the time when the pointer returned by `bufCirGet()` is used.